# How does health globes drop work?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am trying to understand if there is a logic in health/life globes drops in order to setup a correct strategy in monster killing order. Are they completely random in chance and "size"? Are there monsters (types) that guarantee the drop of a life globe on death or at least that guarantee a certain globe "size" when it drops?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is gonna still drop in inferno

Comment: @Michel They have to, otherwise a large swath of builds would be invalidated, and the game would become nearly impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a logic in health globes drop, at least when dealing with elite enemies (blue, yellow mobs):

- **Blue monsters**: 60% chance to drop at 50% and 0% life.
- **Yellow monster**: 100% chance at 75%, 50%, 25% and 0% life.

Also, Health Globes dropped from blue and yellow monsters restore 35% of your life (+ boost on equipment) as opposed to 20% from globes dropped by normal monsters.

Normal monsters instead only drop them at death, and the odds depends on the monster.

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/uavgf/how_to_make_elites_drop_health_globes/)

Answer (score 1):

*From my experience*, a health globe is guaranteed if you eliminate:

- a `unique` or `elite` monster (ones with gold or purple above their heads)
- a group of minions with the blue bar above their heads

This is not including the chance from killing other randoms around the world and *this is just speaking from my experience*.