# How does Pound of Flesh bonus work with Health Globe drop rates and bonuses?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

There is a very good [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/71166/27839) to a question about generic drop rates, but how do those changes if you are using Pound of Flesh?

- How does P.o.F. effect drop rates if you are playing in a group setting?
- Would Elite (Blue) monsters go from 60% drop at 50/0% life up to a 70% or 85% chance to drop a globe?
- (My instinct is that it would be 70% because most things in Diablo 3 seem to be multiplicative)
- Does the +25% to health globe drops then not affect Rare (Yellow) monsters at all?
- In a group setting, does everyone in the party benefit from that (if so, what happens with multiple barbs using pound of flesh)?
- Or is it only if you, as the barb, are the one who drops the target below their normal drop check mark?
- Also, has anyone tested if the 100% bonus to life healed from health globe is applied before or after item bonus to heal?
  (Here my guess is that it only multiplies the base amount from 20%/35% to 40%/70% and then adds item bonuses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pound of Flesh Increases chance of finding a health globe by 25%, and you gain 100% additional life from health globes.  This you already know, but to answer your question, it has the following effect:

The chance to drop increases by 25% of the original drop rate.  As an example, a Hulking Phasebeast has a 60% drop rate, with a globe size of 20.  With PoF, it will increase the drop rate by 15% (which is 25% of 60%), giving you a drop chance of 75% with a globe size of 20.  The globe sizes aren't changed.

The 100% additional life form health globes effectly doubles any healing you receive from the globe when you or another player collects it.  Item heal bonuses are calculated separately, so things like Life on Hit, or Life on Death are calculated and applied when those events happen.  Picking up a globe is its own event.

All monsters, normal, rare, champion and unique will have their chances increased.  For unique monsters which have a set number of drops (like Diablo,), then the only benefit you get is when you or another player collects those globes.

This passive skill still works if you are not the one dealing the killing blow.  If you are close to a monster which is being killed - even by another player, the drop chance will still be increased, just like you will get experience from the kill, and just like you will get the kill registered in your massacre bonus (if any).

This effect does not stack if you have other barbarians in the game, just like Monk mantras of the same kind (e.g. Mantra of Evasion) do not stack.

Source: Diablo 3 Brady Games Guide, plus personal experience.